# Sitemaps: How do you illustrate drop down menu labels?

Tags: sitemap, deliverables

When presenting a sitemap for a client and you are using a drop down menu or a mega menu as navigation - how do you illustrate that the menu post that the user would click on to show the links to the sub pages isn't an own page but only a link?

For example you could have a menu post that say Our offices. When the user clicks on Our offices the page lists the offices (such as London, New York, Tokyo etc) in a drop down menu. Our offices isn't a page but London etc is.

Answer (score 3):

I think this could be handled by providing simple affordance. If it looks like a generic link, it will be a link. If it looks like a button, it will be a button.

If you want to increase the affordance in your Mega Menu, you may want to consider:

> A down-pointing arrow next to each horizontal menu item or a right-pointing arrow next to a vertical menu item is a pretty standard affordance (see OfficeDepot.com or Walmart.com). This affordance implies a hidden secondary menu; no need to have anything additional identifying the menu as a “mega menu”. – [Mega menus: Spool vs Nielsen](http://blogs.perficient.com/spark/2011/08/24/mega-menus-spool-vs-nielsen/)

Just make sure you have fully fleshed out your Information Architecture in order to help the user understand the category names and trigger words so they know where they want to browse.